# Does PouchDB Quick Search look for partial matches?

Tags: pouchdb

I have integrated the PouchDB-Quick-Search plugin into my project.  The search functionality works fine, but seemingly only if I include an entire term (during testing) that I know is in the database.  Partial terms do not seem to return any results, and the API does not throw any errors.

The searchInputInfo variable is based on user input.

```
 DTDB.search({
        query: searchInputInfo,
        fields: ['type', 'description', 'notes'],
        include_docs: true,
        highlighting: true})
.then(function (result) {
}).catch(function (error){
});
```

Finally, whenever I include the 'build' option, the search doesn't work at all.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 1):

From the docs:

> **Autosuggestions and prefix search**
>
> While the `pouchdb-quick-search` plugin does not provide
>   prefix/autosuggestion support, you can trivially do it in PouchDB
>   itself by using `allDocs()`.
>
> Just create documents with IDs equal to what you want to search for,
>   and then use `startkey`/`endkey` plus the special high unicode character `\uffff` to search:

```
pouch.bulkDocs([
    {_id: 'marin'},
    {_id: 'mario'},
    {_id: 'marth'},
    {_id: 'mushroom'},
    {_id: 'zelda'}
 ]).then(function () { 
   return pouch.allDocs({
     startkey: 'mar',
     endkey: 'mar\uffff'
   });
 });
```

> This will return all documents that start with `'mar'`, which in this case would be `'marin'`, `'mario'`, and `'marth'`.
>
> How does it work? Well, in PouchDB and CouchDB, doc IDs are [sorted
>   lexiocographically](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/couchapp/views/collation.html), hence the `\uffff` trick.
>
> Note that to handle uppercase/lowercase, you would have to insert the
>   documents with the `_id`s already lowercase, and then search using
>   lowercase letters as well.
>
> **Note:** You can also accomplish this using [map/reduce queries](http://pouchdb.com/guides/queries.html), and the
>   principle is the same (including the `\uffff` trick). However, the
>   performance may be worse than `allDocs()` because you are using a
>   secondary index rather than the primary index.